when i click the job in jenkins dashboard the below error got
Started by user Arvind Surala
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:222)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:213)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:191)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:118)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:70)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:311)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
Finished: FAILURE

when i build the dev jobs in jenkins dashboard and also i need to mention is my jenkins version is 2.364 and also im not able to see credentials section in jenkins dashboard. How can i achieve this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
